# How to detect errors of invalid URL in Worker API

Tags: javascript, exception

If I run the following (at least on Chromium):

```
var w = null;
try {
    w = new Worker( 'NONEXISTENT_URL' );
}
catch ( e ) {
    console.log( 'CAUGHT: ' + e );
}
console.log( w );
```

...no exception is caught, even though the argument to the [`Worker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) constructor does not point to a valid filename.  Moreover, the console shows `Worker {}`, indicating that `w` now holds a (non-functional) instance of `Worker`.

Other error conditions are also possible.  For example, argument to the constructor may be available and readable, but not contain valid JavaScript.

How else can I detect such error conditions?

(BTW: Please assume that the browser supports the `Worker` API.)

Answer (score 1):

You can get error using [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbstractWorker/onerror) event handler.

```
var worker = new Worker('aURL');

worker.onerror = function () {
    console.log( 'error' );
};
```

> If the URL has an invalid syntax or if the same-origin policy is violated a [DOMException](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMException) of type SECURITY_ERR is thrown.

Comment: Don't thiknk this would work all the time since you're setting onerror **after** the url load.

Comment: @Pacerier it actually does work: the constructor itself doesn't throw, but onerror gets triggered. However, the onerror is async so you don't know when it's going to happen.