# How do I detect an invalid URL being given to Worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

The following questions are very similar; however, neither of them have a solution that works for me, I have a bit more additional info to provide, and I don't have enough rep to comment on either of them:

[How to detect errors of invalid URL in Worker API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102658/how-to-detect-errors-of-invalid-url-in-worker-api)

[web worker constructor does not fail even with invalid file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599137/web-worker-constructor-does-not-fail-even-with-invalid-file-path)

If the Worker constructor is given an invalid URL, is there a way that I can definitively determine that this was the cause of the error that is thrown:

```
var w = new Worker("badurl");
w.onerror = function (event) {
    console.error(event);
};
```

The problem with the above code is that the `event` object that is thrown is a plain `Event` object with it's `type` set to `error`, not an `ErrorEvent` object, as is thrown when a runtime exception is encountered. The basic `Event` object doesn't seem to include any useful details as far as I can tell.

This problem originally arose from a problem I was having with the library [hsl.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/). A [bug in v71 of Chrome](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3463) caused the `URL.createObjectUrl()` to create an invalid URL, so in this instance, trying to validate the URL before creating the worker probably wouldn't be a solution.

I would like to suggest an improvement for the library (as its error handling logic expects `ErrorEvent` properties to always be present).

I was originally going to report this a bug in Chrome, but after further testing, it seems that Chrome, Firefox, and Edge all handle the following jsfiddle in the manner I have described above: https://jsfiddle.net/q08b62ry/

I didn't see anything in the spec (www.w3.org/TR/workers) concerning invalid url errors specifically.

Does anyone have any additional info that may be useful? Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @KoshVery The expected result would be that `event` is an instance of `ErrorEvent` (with all the expected properties), not just `Event`.